# Multiple APK signing - signature protectionLevel behavior

Tags: android, android-permissions

Suppose the following situation:

I have 2 apps: A1 & A2.

A1 defines a signature level permission, lets say "com.example.myapp.PERMISSION".

A2 claims the permission defined by A1.

I have 2 signing keys: K1 & K2.

A1 is signed with both K1 & K2.
A2 is signed with only K1.

If A1 exposes a service that is protected by the "com.example.myapp.PERMISSION" permission, can A2 access that service? Do all signatures have to be present for both apps, or will it work as long as there is a match between any two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android treats all the signatures as Set - 2 applications must have the same Set of signatures to be considered equivalent. So in your example A2 would not be granted the permission since it's signature set does not equals A1's.

Here is the code from the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-cts-5.1_r9/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#2799)

```
    ArraySet<Signature> set1 = new ArraySet<Signature>();
    for (Signature sig : s1) {
        set1.add(sig);
    }
    ArraySet<Signature> set2 = new ArraySet<Signature>();
    for (Signature sig : s2) {
        set2.add(sig);
    }
    // Make sure s2 contains all signatures in s1.
    if (set1.equals(set2)) {
        return PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH;
    }
    return PackageManager.SIGNATURE_NO_MATCH;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is incorrect/incomplete for modern versions of Android. See the AOSP source (specifically `frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/permission/PermissionManagerServiceImpl.java`) for a detailed set of conditions:

```java
private boolean shouldGrantPermissionBySignature(@NonNull AndroidPackage pkg,
    @NonNull Permission bp) {
// expect single system package
String systemPackageName = ArrayUtils.firstOrNull(mPackageManagerInt.getKnownPackageNames(
        KnownPackages.PACKAGE_SYSTEM, UserHandle.USER_SYSTEM));
final AndroidPackage systemPackage =
        mPackageManagerInt.getPackage(systemPackageName);
// check if the package is allow to use this signature permission.  A package is allowed to
// use a signature permission if:
//     - it has the same set of signing certificates as the source package
//     - or its signing certificate was rotated from the source package's certificate
//     - or its signing certificate is a previous signing certificate of the defining
//       package, and the defining package still trusts the old certificate for permissions
//     - or it shares a common signing certificate in its lineage with the defining package,
//       and the defining package still trusts the old certificate for permissions
//     - or it shares the above relationships with the system package
final SigningDetails sourceSigningDetails =
        getSourcePackageSigningDetails(bp);
return sourceSigningDetails.hasCommonSignerWithCapability(
                pkg.getSigningDetails(),
                SigningDetails.CertCapabilities.PERMISSION)
        || pkg.getSigningDetails().hasAncestorOrSelf(systemPackage.getSigningDetails())
        || systemPackage.getSigningDetails().checkCapability(
                pkg.getSigningDetails(),
                SigningDetails.CertCapabilities.PERMISSION);
}
```

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/refs/heads/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/permission/PermissionManagerServiceImpl.java;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=3384